# Building standalone libraries

Tags: android, c++, c, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile a big project to android (too big to port it to the ndk-build format). I come from the Java world so I'm quite new to all these compilation, C, C++. The thing is the following:

This big project, uses xerces-c as a library which at its time depends on the ICU Transcoder. I have cross-compiled both of them resulting in libxerces-c.a, libicuuc.a and libicudata.a

When I cross compile my big project, the configure checks the headers  (they are) and the xerces-c library. However, when I run the make command, the execution fails because -licuuc -licudata are not on the compilation command.

Is there a way to create a standalone libxerces-c that includes libicuuc and libicudata? Some flag that I can include in the CFLAGS, CXXFLAGS or LDFLAGS? Some parameter on the configure script?

As I'm quite new on this, an example would be quite useful.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What's wrong with just specifying the needed additional libraries to the linker?

Comment: That I need to change the makefiles (several) and that this happens with 9 libraries. Not just xerces-c so at the end I end up with 1000 -l flags. I just want to know if there's any way to do it and save all the time of changing 20K-lines configures and makefiles

Comment: Compiler / linker flags are implementation-specific.  There may be a way to achieve what you ask, but it would depend on your (cross) compiler.

Comment: Alternatively, your mention of `configure` scripts suggests that you may have an Autoconf-based build system.  If that's so, then you may be able to make changes in a small number of small(ish) `configure.ac` or `configure.in` files to add the needed libraries to the link.  That's pretty much a certainty if the build system also uses Automake.

Comment: Or as another alternative, try running `configure --help`.  With an Autotools build system, at least, that will give you information about all the options and variables you can adjust to tweak build behavior.  Some of them are standard to Autotools-based build systems; others may be project specific.

Comment: As you suggest the build system is based on autoconf and automake. I've already run the configure --help and there I can add, for instance, a library that can be used for linking. The thing is that I dont want to add that library to every command, just for those commands loading the libxerxes-c library. I should change the .ac and .in to look for both of them. But again there might be more libraries using xerxes (eg opensaml + my project). I want to avoid this cascade effect

Comment: Btw, I'm using the default ndk compiler for armeabi

Answer (score 0):

In Makefiles you can define expressions to be used in all command lines.  If you use this facility correctly you can have the same command on as many ( or few ) files as you want.  In Makefiles you see from other projects you'll see people commonly use CFLAGS for ( surprise  ) flags and options for the C compiler, and LIBS for things intended for the linker, but you can use any name you like for macros.

You can also define lists of files to operate on and files they depend on.

On Linux some packages also have a configuration file installed that lets an applications called [`pkg-config`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) be used to find out all the flags and library options for that package.  This avoids having to hardwire explicit paths into a Makefile.

Here are a couple of tutorials :

[Simple tutorial.](http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/)

[Another intro](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html)